# Return stream from custom data structure class

Tags: java, generics, interface, linked-list, java-stream

I am working on a program that creates a custom LinkedList generic class, and I would like to be able to generate a stream from it by calling stream() on an object.  I have looked in the docs, and did not find anything that can help me do this, like an interface to implement (similarly... iterable, comparator, comparable).  I was thinking of creating a stream method, that returns a stream with Arrays.stream, from an array generated by iterating through the linked list and assigning elements.  Is this okay, also this generic class I would like to have its parameters constrained to two classes which do not have an inheritance relationship. Kind of like < Person or Alien > could that be accomplished

Comment: The definition of stream function is defined in `Collection` interface (as a default method for compatibility reasons), it relies on implementation of `Spliterator` for the collection. You can read about spliterators here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html

Comment: It's probably easiest to extend `Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator` for your `Spliterator` implementation.

Comment: If you want your own `LinkedList` implementation to create a stream similar to how the built-in `java.util.LinkedList` does it, I'd suggest you simply look at the source code for `java.util.LinkedList`, to see how to do it.

Comment: @Andreas could you refer to a location that I can find it.  The pages I saw did not have stream method.

Comment: How about the second question, is it possible to declare your own acceptable parameters as type for generic class

Comment: @DannyP. Do you have JDK 8? Then it has a `src.zip` file. Any good IDE will automatically show you the source of any class in there for you. I know Eclipse does (e.g. using F3 or Ctrl+Shift+T), because I use it all the time.

Comment: Yes, I'll have to look at this on my computer

Comment: You cannot use `Person or Alien` as a type argument for `CustomList<T>`; you have to use a type or interface which is extended/implemented by both.  Otherwise, when your iterator extracts an entity from the list, the only methods that the compiler will allow you to use would be those defined on an `Object`, which will always be a common ancestor for both `Person` and `Alien`, despite saying the classes have no inheritance relationship.

Comment: What is it this custom linked list class will do that the standard `LinkedList<T>` class cannot?  What is its raison d'être?  Are you just implementing a your own class for practice, or to get a better understanding of how the conversion from list to stream works?  Or, do you think there is missing functionality in the standard class that needs to be added?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your custom LinkedList class has an iterator() method. I also assume that it has a constant time size() method.  Making these assumptions you could implement the stream() method using the following code:

```
public Stream<T> stream() {
    Iterator<T> it = iterator();
    int characteristics = 0;  // see characteristics docs in [Spliterator][1]
    Spliterator<T> spliterator = Spliterators.spliterator(it, size(), charactistics);  // see [Spliterators][2]
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false);  // see [StreamSupport][3]
}
```